Google Vault API -- Google Voice 403 Issues

My current code:
def __api_create_export(
    access_token, matter_id, org_unit_id: str, start_time: arrow.Arrow, end_time: arrow.Arrow
):
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
    url = f"https://vault.googleapis.com/v1/matters/{matter_id}/exports"

    data = {
        "exportOptions": {"voiceOptions": {"exportFormat": "MBOX"}},
        "name": f"export_{start_time.format('YYYYMMDD')}",
        "query": {
            "corpus": "VOICE",
            "method": "ORG_UNIT",
            "startTime": start_time.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "T0:00:00Z",
            "endTime": end_time.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "T0:00:00Z",
            "dataScope": "ALL_DATA",
            "orgUnitInfo": {"orgUnitId": org_unit_id},  # id, starting with "id:"
        },
    }

    
    return requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, timeout=10).json()

My error
{'error': {'code': 403, 'message': 'The caller does not have permission', 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}}

What I've tried:

Using the HANGOUTS_CHAT corpus instead (to pull Google Chat instead of Google Voice) -- it completes successfully, with the change of the
corpus to "HANGOUTS_CHAT" and the exportOptions to:

{"hangoutsChatOptions": {"exportFormat": "MBOX"}}
Where I think the solution lies:

I think the answer is around scopes. My access token has the following scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ediscovery
The Google Vault API
mentions that these are the only scopes needed, though


There's also the possibility that I need certain Vault "privileges"



It's almost always easier|better to use the Google-provided APIs rather than script REST calls against services. Here's a Python quickstart for Vault. How are you obtaining access_token?
